# How can I connect Python code to an Arducam camera on an Arduino, both using the same COM port, without 'Access denied' errors?"

Tags: python, arduino-uno, arducam

In this scenario, im attempting to integrate Python code with an Arducam camera that is connected to an Arduino board. Both the Arducam camera and the Python code need to communicate with the Arduino over the same COM port. However, when attempting to run the Python code, which sends commands to the Arduino, an "Access denied" error occurs due to the COM port being already occupied by the Arducam initialization,

is there a way I can solve this problem and make them share the same port without any problem?

Comment: Why do they both need to use the same port?

Comment: I used the python code for object tracking using opencv, now I need it to communicate with the arduino code but the com port is already occupied by the ardcam

Comment: AFAIK, you can't. I recommend just getting a 2nd usb serial adapter. You can't have 2 things physically plugged in to the same port. Maybe you can add more info - like how it is currently wired up.

Comment: The camera is connected to the Arduino, see the connection diagram here: https://www.arducam.com/knowledge-base/mini-tutorial/

I then wrote a code to receive a command from the python code (The object tracking code using OpenCV), So first I initialize the camera through its interface by then it occupies the com port, which means the python code wont work

Comment: To try to integrate the python code, Im importing pyserial in the python code, and trying to initialize the sae port occupied by the Arduino and camera

Comment: According to the diagram, the camera is using I2C ports and not the serial port. And according to this, you should be able to use both at the same time: [I2C and Serial Communications simultaneously?](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/i2c-and-serial-communications-simultaneously/142299)

Comment: Note: there is an entire Stack Overflow site dedicated to Arduino. You might find more help there: [arduino.se]. I've never used Arducam so it is unclear how you get the image from the camera, through the Arduino, to the PC.

Comment: Yes it uses I2C but when initialized and when you click open, it occupies the port connected to the Arduino , https://docs.arducam.com/picture/spi-camera/Arducam_host_v2-1.png